# Python Install Error: AttributeError: BetterRotatingFileHandler instance has no attribute 'filters'

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, pip

After trying to install numpy and pandas on my Mac OS 10.6.8 (using python 2.6.1), I ran into a large error that comes up every time I try to install a library (like pandas and numpy). I have not seen it before and I can't google my way out of it.

Here is the error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/commands/install.py", line 339, in run
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 235, in prepare_files
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/index.py", line 305, in find_requirement
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/index.py", line 795, in _get_page
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/index.py", line 884, in get_page
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 473, in get
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/download.py", line 332, in request
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 461, in request
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 610, in send
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/_vendor/requests/models.py", line 728, in content
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/_vendor/requests/models.py", line 653, in generate
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 256, in stream
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 186, in read
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 54, in read
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 213, in cache_response
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/download.py", line 239, in set
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/caches/file_cache.py", line 83, in set
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/_vendor/lockfile/__init__.py", line 173, in __init__
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'int'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==6.0.3', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/__init__.py", line 217, in main
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pip/pip/basecommand.py", line 241, in main
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1065, in critical
    self._log(CRITICAL, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1129, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1139, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1176, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 658, in handle
    rv = self.filter(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 558, in filter
    for f in self.filters:
AttributeError: BetterRotatingFileHandler instance has no attribute 'filters'
```

Any thoughts on what I could do to be able to install libaries (could this be an issue with pip?)

Comment: what version of 2.6?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Python 2.6.1 (the default version)

Comment: might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465073/rotatingfilehandler-throws-an-exception-when-delay-parameter-is-set

Comment: @PadraicCunningham So do you think that its related to some kind of a bug with Python 2.6.1? If so, should I be using a different version of python?

Comment: To be honest if you are not using 2.6 for some specific reason I would update to the latest which I think is 2.7.9, there have been a lot of improvements and bug fixes since 2.6.1

Comment: You should definitely be using a different version. If you have to use 2.6, 2.6.9 is the latest. If you don't, consider 2.7.9 or upgrading to 3.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I was told that updating my default python version could mess up some internal mechanisms of my computer, is this totally wrong (just want to double check before upgrading)?

Comment: There are various approaches, personally I have a /usr/local/bin/python install along with my system python in ubuntu. The real danger would be changing your system default to python3 as it is not backwards compatible.  There is a step by step blog post here http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/